# Does Injecting many dependencies in a ViewModel affect the performance?

Tags: kotlin, dependency-injection, viewmodel, dagger-hilt, android-mvvm

Does Injecting too many dependencies using dagger hilt in a ViewModel affect the performance of an android application?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, increasing dependency will just increase build time for dagger hilt as dagger hilt provide dependency at compile time. So, it will not affect app performance.